# Databricks error while reading GTiff file using RasterIO

Tags: azure-databricks, geotiff, rasterio

While reading raster file in Databricks getting below error:

```
ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Error while obtaining a new communication channel
```

Code:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.plot
import pyproj
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp

raster = rasterio.open('/dbfs/mnt/Firescar/cvmsre_201909_afka2.tif')
raster.read(1)
```